# jQuery .click() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I generate the set of buttons within html table as follows and then I want to call to function when it click.

```
$.each(childData, function(key, item) {
    var packPath = key.replace(/_/g, "/"); //Replace underscore with slash

    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<td>'+key+'</td>'
                + '<td><button type="button" data-id="'+key+'" class="download btn btn-success btn-xs">Originals</li></td></div>'; 

})
```

This is how I call the function but it's not working.

```
$(".download").click(function(){
    alert();
});
```

Where is the wrong in above code?

Comment: Try calling `$(".download").click(function(){ alert(); });` after you run `$.each()` instead of before.

Comment: why would a div have td as children? That is not valid HTML.

Comment: @epascarello Because table and table headers are already created in the html page.

Comment: whic jquery version you are using ?

Comment: @VforVendetta jQuery v1.11.3

Comment: Then use $(document).on("click",".download", function(){//your code});

Comment: @VforVendetta Yes It works. Thanks.

Comment: `</td></div>"` <-- that is the div that makes no sense.... You should be appending table rows to a table...

Comment: @epascarello Oh got the point. You are correct.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.download', function(){ 
     // Your Code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Delegate the event to static parent:

```
$(div).on("click", ".download", function(){
```

Here `div` can be the static parent which was available when page was loaded at first load. Although `document` or `body` can also be used in place of `div`.

---

As you have not presented how you create `div` element but one thing has to be noticed that you are generating an invalid markup. As a `td` element can't be a child of `div` but `table`'s `tr`.

Comment: Does this bypass the requirement to rebuild the hook after content on the page has changed ?  (eg and new `div` with `.download` class )

Comment: See, `new div` means it is not the static parent, as mentioned in the answer that parent should have to be static at first load which comes from the server.

Comment: Pretty neat.   That will save some time :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation.

If your table has an id of "button-table", you can create an event handler like so:

```
$("#button-table").on("click",function(e){
    var target = e.target;
    console.log($(target).attr("data-id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it this way? I have given code for adding an entire table.Check this out

```js
function generate_table() {
  // get the reference for the body
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
 
  // creates a <table> element and a <tbody> element
  var tbl     = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
 
  // creating all cells
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    // creates a table row
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
 
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      // Create a <td> element and a text node, make the text
      // node the contents of the <td>, and put the <td> at
      // the end of the table row
      var cell = document.createElement("td");
      var cellText = document.createTextNode("cell in row "+i+", column "+j);
      cell.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
 
    // add the row to the end of the table body
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
 
  // put the <tbody> in the <table>
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  // appends <table> into <body>
  body.appendChild(tbl);
  // sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
  tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Generate a table." onclick="generate_table()">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".download").click(function(){
     alert();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="downlaod">Download</button>
```

Comment: Waiting for dom ready, is a good shout but probably already being used. Your answer wouldn’t solve the issue, the `.download` buttons are being added dynamically, so any new buttons won’t have the click handler applied. That is why the accepted answer is using delegation to attatch the event handler to the document and passing the `.button` as the selector trigger of the event.